# Generate List of Dates Excluding Weekends

Tags: excel, powerbi, powerquery, powerbi-desktop, m

I have a list of targets, but only containing monthly number. I want to modify this to allow daily display but excluding weekends and somehow cannot find the right way to achieve that.

We have a list:
[example] (https://i.stack.imgur.com/p0JLF.png)

I've tried listing the dates by adding additional custom columns as following.

`= List.Dates([Date], Date.Day(Date.EndOfMonth([Date])), #duration(1, 0, 0, 0))

and then calculating daily target as following:
Daily Target 1 = [Target1]/Date.DaysInMonth([Date])

Daily Target 2 = [Target2]/Date.DaysInMonth([Date])

Daily Target 3 = [Target3]/Date.DaysInMonth([Date])`

But in this approach, we have these unconformities, because the parts of the targets are dedicated to weekends which should not take place.

These targets should be divided between monday-friday invterval only. How to do it?

Thanks in advance for advisory.

| Date | Target 1 | Target 2 | Target 3 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| April-22 | 19541 | 25855 | 3726 |
| May-22 | 17047 | 37222 | 5646 |
| June-22 | 8745 | 38158 | 6592 |
| July-22 | 16600 | 36299 | 3671 |

EDIT: What I achieved:
[image]

for example tcn20/21/22 is monthly target value, and next to it we have daily target already. and so on for tcn14 and so on

But I don't want to include in the calculations saturdays and sundays. Target should be divided on 5 days in a week, not on 7. The best if for saturdays and sundays we would have "0" displayed.

Comment: Please paste you sample data as copiable text

Comment: Here you go. updated.

Comment: What should your expected result look like?

Comment: added additional edit with explanation

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**UPDATE**

To get the correct number of days:

```
[Target1]/List.Count([Name of New Column Generated Below])
```

This removes Saturday and Sunday from your generated list.

[image]

[image]

```
List.RemoveNulls( List.Transform( List.Dates([Date], Date.Day(Date.EndOfMonth([Date])), #duration(1, 0, 0, 0)), each if Date.DayOfWeek(_, Day.Monday) <>5 and Date.DayOfWeek(_, Day.Monday) <>6  then _ else null ))
```

Comment: okay perfect! That's one, but now how to get the monthly target divided on the list created above?
Because we have monthly value still divided by full 30/31 days in a month instead of working days in a month.

Comment: Great! Let me just check if all works as necessary and i'll do so!
Thanks!

Comment: seems like all is as i wanted to be. Thanks so much!!!